# JavaFx with login

Tags: java, javafx, authentication

I want to make an JavaFx application where you can login. I already have a file with the encrypted password and all in all the login already works. But now I don't know how to check if the user is logged in, while he is doing something. Just set a boolean in the main class to true? I don't know hot to do this. Maybe you can help me.

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/SimpleLoginTextFileFx

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty simple,

First of All You will receiver the Information of the User and Will store that information such as User name and Password in variables and then you will check from database whether User Exists or not.

I will suggest you to not discard these variables whether user has successfully logged in or not.

Then you can also use these variables to do communication in other Stages or Scenes.

Making it simple, store Information in variable and don't discard them.

That's it.

Comment: I don't have a database.

Comment: Use static fields in the main application.

Comment: Can't this be hacked, when you have the programm? When you decompile it?

Comment: It is within the code, whey there is a need to provide or show the code to someone?

Comment: @TheGaming If your program is the only thing that controlls access to whatever you're trying to protect there, sure. You can replace the bytecode checking access with any code that simply returns success on the check, but ***any other java program*** executed with the same privileges could gain the same level of access. Looks like you either have some security on the resource you're accessing or you don't have the access to the resource secured at all.